# Ionic 2 http.post formdata null values on php server side

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I use FormData to send data to the server. I can log in but the values for device and device_token are null on the server side.

Here is the code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class Auth{

    credentials = {
        username:'',
        password:'',
        token:'',
        device:'ios',
        device_token:'ios'
    }
    headers:any;
    constructor(public http:Http){ 
    }

    Login(credentials)
    {
        let newCredentials: FormData = new FormData();
        newCredentials.append("device",credentials.device);
        newCredentials.append("device_token",credentials.device_token);
        newCredentials.append("username",credentials.username);
        newCredentials.append("password",credentials.password);


        return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
            let headers = new Headers();
            headers.append('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            console.log("body: "+ "username: " + newCredentials.get("username"));
            console.log("body: "+ "password: " + newCredentials.get("password"));
            console.log("body: "+ "device: " + newCredentials.get("device"));
            console.log("body: "+ "device_token: " + newCredentials.get("device_token"));

            this.headers = {headers}
            this.http.post('http://www.example.com/api/login/',newCredentials,this.headers)
            .map(res => res)
            .subscribe(res=>{
                var resJson = res.json();
                this.credentials.token = resJson.token;
                resolve(res);
            },(err) =>{
                reject(err);
                console.log(err.error);
            });
        });
    }
```

I have tried with Postman and the values for `device` and `device_token` on the server weren't null.

Comment: First things first, what are `credentials.device` and `credentials.device_Token` when `Login` is called?

Comment: `credentials.device='ios', credentials.device_token='oiadfjiojqwe'` are some strings

Answer (score 0):

If you use `FormData`, the request will automatically be `multipart/form-data` rather than `x-www-form-urlencoded` even if you set the header explicitly. This will still work if you are willing to handle the multipart form data on the server side, but it's not really necessary unless you're uploading files. Instead you can use `URLSearchParams` or even just a query string formatted string.

```
    let newCredentials = new URLSearchParams();
    newCredentials.set("device",credentials.device);
    newCredentials.set("device_token",credentials.device_token);
    newCredentials.set("username",credentials.username);
    newCredentials.set("password",credentials.password);
    newCredentials = newCredentials.toString();
```

On another note, you don't need to wrap this in a Promise yourself. Instead, I would suggest returning the observable stream from `.http.post`:

```
return this.http.post(...props).map(res => res.json()).map(resJson => {
  this.credentials.token = resJson.token;
  return resJson;
});
```

Now you will have to use `.subscribe` in whatever code calls the `auth.Login` method.

If you really want to use promises, you can also use `.toPromise()` on `this.http.post()` which will do what your code is already doing now.

Comment: on server side I use: example.com/api/login  

username: the username
password: the password
device: 'a sting'
device_token: 'another_string'

not username=theusername&password=thepassword....

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: the body for http.post is different using URLSearchParams, I don't need to join `&` between parameters.

Comment: @MarianRencsik yes you do, that's what a `x-www-form-urlencoded` request body looks like